# C++Builder IDE randomly changes the width of controls?

Tags: c++builder

I find here and there the IDE 11.3 all of a sudden changes the width of controls to be smaller, as a result the right margin gets too big.   This last time the only think I think of is I went in to text view of the .dfm and back out (I didn't actually change anything).   Is there some quirk or bug known or something I have to do to prevent it?